# Should I retake GRE?

Tags: gre

I took the GRE two times, and unfortunately, I could not improve my score on the second attempt. I considered applying with my current GRE score which is 160Q and 140V.(Ps. English is my second language and the verbal part if helpless for me. I do not think that I can improve my verbal score; however, I can make the Quant better.)I am so confused about retaking the GRE a third time. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: You've taken it twice with similar results -- why do you think a third attempt will be better?

Comment: Perhaps these types of questions (standardized tests as they relate to admissions) warrant a sticked or meta question?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for joining the site. Others have asked similar questions [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/retake-the-math-gre-as-a-grad-student-preparing-to-transfer?rq=1), [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134603/took-gre-two-times-same-scores-with-minor-differences-worth-sending-both?rq=1), and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/112171/what-is-the-weight-of-gre-analytical-writing-scores-on-math-graduate-program-adm?rq=1) (all relating to standardized tests and scores). You might also benefit from a [general discussion about admissions decisions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125487/how-can-anyone-assess-their-own-phd-application-prior-to-actually-applying-to-de/126136#126136). There is a general consensus is that test scores are only one component of an application. You might consider focusing on a supplementary letter explaining the lower verbal score or focusing your efforts on other assessments of language (such as the TOEFL, if required).